# How To find distinct URI(pattern) from logs using log Parser? (-i:Textline)

Tags: parsing, logging, logparser

I have large size logs and need find the reverse proxy and the count of the distinct uri. The format of the log is as below:

```
Jan 29  0:03:07 fpp-mp-a01  127.3.0.0   -   33.42.670.281, 126.7.0.0    akman_t1    CN=U-100927121845499116,OU=K,OU=A,OU=External,OU=Persons,O=indigo   Form    [29/Jan/2014:00:03:07   +0200]  POST /amm-server-serv4/main HTTP/1.1    200 246 6454    -   Java/1.8.0_45

Jan 29  0:03:07 fpp-mp-a01  127.3.0.0   -   81.58.160.252           Not Protected   [29/Jan/2014:00:03:07   +0200]  GET /flyworld HTTP/1.1  302 494 452 -   Wget/1.11.4 Red Hat modified
```

Here, I want to find out all the uri after the method "GET /flyworld" i.e fly world, amm-server-serv4, etc. in the logs and the total sum of count.

Comment: It's not clear what character is used as separator of the fields. Is that a tab between the fields? Does the tab only appear between a field and another, and never within a field?

Comment: Hello Gabriele, There seems no tab between fields as its in notepad. I copied the logs into excel file in order to get a view of it. I paste below the exact log from Notepad:

Comment: Jun 29 00:03:24 frd-rp-p01 127.6.0.0 -  "82.241.3.207, 127.4.0.0"  "-" "-" "Auto" [29/Jun/2015:00:03:24 +0200] "GET /_layouts/1033/ie55up.js?rev=Ni7%2Fj2ZV%2FzCvd09XYSSWvA%3D%3D HTTP/1.1" 200 105258 103702 "https://w4.flygo.com/sites/F3D_Extended_FBI_MSI/_layouts/airNotif/NotificationCustomPage.aspx?weburl=https://w4.flygo.com/sites/F3D_Extended_FBI_MSI&listid={D57EACDA-FF62-433E-9375-511C53EB2E3B}&itemid=1790" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"

Comment: Hello I Tried below Query: 
LOGPARSER "Select Count(Text) AS Hits from C:\LOGS\*.log where Text like '%POST /%' OR Text Like '%GET /%' GROUP BY TEXT" -i:TEXTLINE -q:Off -o:DATAGRID          But i am not able to get the total count of each distinct uri.

Comment: So, if there are no tabs, it looks like N spaces, with N >  1, is a good heuristic for the field separator. In that case, use the TSV input format, specifying 'space' for the separator character, and 2 for the minimum number of separator characters. When you do so, the URI should end up consistently in the 12th field, which you can then GROUP BY on.

Comment: So can you tell me what will be the query look like? which function should i use ?

Comment: I am new to log parser , I tried but failed: 

Logparser -i:TSV -o:DATAGRID -nFields:15 -iSeparator:space -nSep:2  -headerRow:OFF "SELECT Field1 AS URI FROM C:\LOGS\*.log Group By Field1"

Comment: Logparser -i:TSV -o:csv -nFields:15 -iSeparator:space -nSep:1  -headerRow:OFF "SELECT EXTRACT_SUFFIX(EXTRACT_prefix(REPLACE_STR(Field15,'GET /',''),1,'/'),0,'/') as URL,Count(*) as Hits into C:\Logs\my_test2.csv  FROM C:\LOGS\*.log GROUP BY URL ORDER BY Hits DESC"